# extreme difference in time between AES-CBC + HMAC and AES-GCM

Tags: c, cryptography, aes-gcm

So I've been searching far and wide for different AES implementations for CBC and GCM, i do not want to implement this my self in case I make mistakes so i have found the following AES CBC codes and tested the speed of them on my RX63NB (Rennesas test board).

```
                    Encrypt                 Decrypt 
                    bytes   speed (us)      bytes   speed (us)
Tiny AES            64      1500            64      8900
                    128     2880            128     17820
aes-byte-29-08-08   64      1250            64      4900
                    128     1220            128     9740
Cyclone             64      230             64      237
                    128     375             128     387
```

I was suprised about how much faster Cyclone was, to clarify I took the AES, CBC and Endian files from [CycloneSSL](http://www.oryx-embedded.com/cyclone_ssl.html) and only used those.

Then I tried GCM from CycloneSSl and this was the output:

```
                    Encrypt                 Decrypt 
                    bytes   speed μs        bytes   speed μs
Cyclone   GCM       64      9340            64      9340
                    128     14900           128     14900
```

I have examained the HMAC time (from CycloneSSL) to see how much that would take:

```
HMAC        bytes   speed μs
Sha1        64      746
            128     857
Sha224      64      918
            128     1066
Sha256      64      918
            128     1066
Sha384      64      2395
            128     2840
Sha512      64      2400
            128     2840
Sha512_224  64      2390
            128     2835
Sha512_356  64      2390
            128     2835
MD5         64      308
            128     345
Whirlpool   64      5630
            128     6420
Tiger       64      832
            128     952
```

The slowest of which is whirlpool.

if you add the cbc encryption time for 128 bytes to the hmac of whirlpool with 128 bytes you get 6795 μs which is about half the time GCM takes.

now I can understand that a GHASH takes a bit longer than HMAC because of the galios field and such but beeing 2 times slower compared to the slowest HASH algorithm I know is insane.

So i've started to wonder if i did anything wrong or if the CycloneSLL gcm implementation is just really show. unfortunatly I have not found an other easy to use GCM implementation in c to compare it with.

All the code i used can be [found on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PUep01Yt), the different files are separated by --------------------

This is the code i use to encrypt with GCM:

```
static void test_encrypt(void)
{
  uint8_t key[] = { 0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c };
  uint8_t iv[]  = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };
  uint8_t in[]  = { 0x48, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x20, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x65, 0x20, 0x67, 0x61, 0x61, 0x74, 0x20, 0x68,
                    0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x6a, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x20, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x64, 0x61,
                    0x61, 0x67, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x6d, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x20, 0x67, 0x61, 0x61, 0x74,
                    0x20, 0x68, 0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x67, 0x6f, 0x65, 0x64, 0x20, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x2e, 0x21,
                    0x48, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x20, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x65, 0x20, 0x67, 0x61, 0x61, 0x74, 0x20, 0x68,
                    0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x6a, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x20, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x64, 0x61,
                    0x61, 0x67, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x6d, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x20, 0x67, 0x61, 0x61, 0x74,
                    0x20, 0x68, 0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x67, 0x6f, 0x65, 0x64, 0x20, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x2e, 0x21};

  AesContext context;
  aesInit(&context, key, 16 ); // 16 byte = 128 bit      
  error_crypto_t error = gcmEncrypt(AES_CIPHER_ALGO, &context, iv, 16, 0, 0, in, in, 128, key, 16);
}

static void test_decrypt(void)
{
  uint8_t key[] = { 0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c };
  uint8_t tag[] = { 0x56, 0x56, 0x5C, 0xCD, 0x5C, 0x57, 0x36, 0x66, 0x73, 0xF7, 0xFF, 0x2A, 0x17, 0x49, 0x0E, 0xC4};
  uint8_t iv[]  = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };
  uint8_t out[] = { 0x05, 0x7C, 0x51, 0xFF, 0xE4, 0x9F, 0x8C, 0x90, 0xF1, 0x7D, 0x56, 0xFB, 0x87, 0xB9, 0x44, 0x79,
                    0xB1, 0x04, 0x32, 0x39, 0x78, 0xFF, 0x51, 0x60, 0x48, 0x0B, 0x21, 0x77, 0xF2, 0x26, 0x0B, 0x94,
                    0x7B, 0xA7, 0x26, 0x74, 0x87, 0xA8, 0x2C, 0x5A, 0xA1, 0x19, 0x03, 0x17, 0x66, 0x3A, 0x46, 0x9F,
                    0xE6, 0x1D, 0x3B, 0x65, 0xFD, 0xC0, 0xBA, 0xC0, 0xD9, 0x45, 0xE7, 0x17, 0x74, 0x0F, 0xB7, 0x4B,
                    0x0F, 0xF0, 0x16, 0xF6, 0xE8, 0x4F, 0xFD, 0x96, 0x64, 0x5E, 0xDB, 0x9E, 0x3A, 0x0B, 0x93, 0x8F,
                    0x87, 0x83, 0x90, 0xF8, 0xF9, 0xE6, 0xA3, 0xE7, 0x5E, 0x72, 0x3C, 0xB5, 0x98, 0x54, 0x11, 0xD7,
                    0xB4, 0x7C, 0xFF, 0xA3, 0x51, 0x1A, 0xB0, 0x69, 0x4F, 0x57, 0xBB, 0x83, 0x40, 0x2A, 0xE6, 0x75,
                    0x8B, 0xB5, 0xCA, 0xA4, 0x84, 0x82, 0x1D, 0xA8, 0x94, 0x03, 0x77, 0x9C, 0x3B, 0xF8, 0xA0, 0x60};

  AesContext context;
  aesInit(&context, key, 16 ); // 16 byte = 128 bit
  error_crypto_t error = gcmDecrypt(AES_CIPHER_ALGO, &context, iv, 16, 0, 0, out, out, 128, tag, 16);
}
```

the data in the out[] is the gcm encrypted data from the in[] and it all works properly. (decrypts correctly and passes authentication.

**Question**

- Are all GCM implementations this slow?
- Are there other (better) GCM implementations?
- Should I just use HMAC if i want a fast encryption + verification?

**EDIT**

I have been able to get the GCM method from [mbedTLS (PolarSSL)](https://tls.mbed.org/source-code) to work which is about 11 times faster than cyclone (it takes 880us do encrypt/decrypt 128 bytes). and it produces the same output as the cylcone GCM so i'm confident this works properly.

```
gcm_context gcm_ctx;
gcm_init(&gcm_ctx, POLARSSL_CIPHER_ID_AES,key, 128);
int error = gcm_auth_decrypt(&gcm_ctx, 128,iv, 16, NULL, 0, tag, 16, out, buffer );
```

Comment: Is it a fair guess that this may be down to the parallel capabilities (or lack thereof) of your board? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode#Performance

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers seem odd, 128 bytes for aes-byte-29-08-08  takes less time than 64 bytes for encryption?

Assuming RX63N is comparable to Cortex-M (they both are 32 bit, no vector unit, and it's difficult to find information on RX63N):

The claimed benchmark for [SharkSSL](https://realtimelogic.com/products/sharkssl/Cortex-M3/) puts CBC at a bit more than twice as fast as GCM, 2.6 if optimized for speed. 9340 is way way larger than 340.

[Cifra](https://github.com/ctz/cifra)'s benchmark shows a 10x difference between their AES and AES-GCM, although the GCM test also included auth-data. Still nowhere close to your differential between straight AES and GCM.

So in relative terms, to answer 1, I don't think all GCM implementations are that slow, relative to plain AES.

As for other GCM implementations, there's the aforementioned Cifra (although I haven't heard of it until just now, and it only has 3 stars on GitHub (if that means anything), so the level of vetting is likely to be rather low), and maybe you can rip out the AES-GCM implementation from [FreeBSD](http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/wpa/src/crypto/). I can't speak about performance though in absolute terms on your platform.

HMAC is likely to be faster on platforms w/o hardware support like  AES-NI support though (CLMUL), regardless of the implementation. How performance critical is this? Do you have to use AES or a block cipher? Perhaps ChaCha20+Poly1305 suits your performance needs better (see performance numbers from Cifra). That's now being used in [OpenSSH](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/usr.bin/ssh/) - chacha.* and poly1305.*

Be aware of side channel attacks. Software implementations of AES can be sensitive to cache timing attacks, although I don't think this is applicable to microcontrollers where everything is in SRAM anyway.

*Salsa20 is ChaCha20's predecessor

Comment: I have tested the Cifra code but this takes 300+ ms for 128 bytes, so it's definitly not fast on the rx63n. i have tried to get the sharkSSL source code but i can only download .exe files. no real code so that's a bummer.

Comment: CBC take 250ms for the cifra code. the difference in speed compared to cycloneSSL is enormous. probably because cifra is made for other controllers.

I need to use AES, we could do the initial part with AES and then switch to a faster stream cipher but AES is mandatory and seeing how fast it is in cbc mode i think that will not be a problem. i just wish we could do GCM, HMAC sha256 is still under 1 ms which is quick enough, i just can't wrap my head around why GCM is taking so much longer.

Comment: 1/3rd of a second for only 128 bytes is ridiculous, and several orders of magnitude over everything else. 300ms*100MHz (max clock for your microcontroller) is 234375 cycles per byte, or 3,750,000 cycles per block, which is 750(!) times more cycles per byte than the published numbers. This is a really unlikely difference, and "being made for other microcontrollers" doesn't explain it, since the difference per byte for that is probably less than 10. in any event, it's a generic C implementation, so not really optimized for anything. Something else is definitely going on.

Comment: Is there a way you can directly get cycle count from registers instead of time values? Perhaps the clock rate isn't consistently being configured?

Comment: For comparison, a desktop PC processor is able to do AES 12 cycles per byte for an optimized assembly implementation. The numbers given for Cifra on Cortex M work out to 193 cycles per byte (277 w/ scheduling), which is an 19x difference, far less than 750. That's two wildly different CPUs, and the desktop is far more capable being superscalar and out of order, and the difference per clock is "only" 19x

Comment: desktop benchmarks: http://bench.cr.yp.to/results-stream.html (ignore HW+AES benchmarks which use AES-NI) - AES CTR should be comparable to CBC speed wise, unless one breaks up the message and computes the keystream in parallel (also a benefit of GCM), but this parallelization is inapplicable to microcontrollers.